# How to get the full size photo from gallery using expo image picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I'm using image picker expo to access my gallery or photos. I want to get the full photo not cropped to be displayed on *image* here is my code:

```js
const image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [1, 1],
        quality: 1,
      });

      if (!image.cancelled) {
        setPickedImage(image.uri);
        setModalVisible(false);
      }
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not yet found how to do this using the library options, so I just created two buttons like *Grop Image* and *Whole Image* and pass allowsEditing as true or false. So the user must decide in advance whether he wants to crop or not and press the appropriate button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comments/delete `allowsEditing: true,`